# Reset Flutter CustomScrollView on state change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I'm building a vertically scrolling calendar and I've implemented my days as multiple `SliverList`s so that I can init with a certain day focused while still having days in the past and future.

The problem is, when the `focusDate` changes via a state change in a parent, the list updates the dates correctly, but keeps its scroll position. For example, if I'm scrolled to the top of the list, then change the `focusDate` the days update, but I'm still at the top of the list.

I'm looking to completely replace the list (not just the days) when the `focusDate` changes. This happens when a date is picked from a date picker. Therefore, new data will need to be fetched anyway and a new `CustomScrollView` can be created and focused on the correct day.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'day.dart';

class DaysManager extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Day> days;

  DaysManager({DateTime focusDate}) {
    final DateTime startDate = focusDate.subtract(Duration(days: 30));
    days = List.generate(61, (int index) {
      return Day(
        date: startDate.add(Duration(days: index)),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildScrollView();
  }

  CustomScrollView _buildScrollView() {
    final focusKey = ValueKey('focus');

    return CustomScrollView(
      center: focusKey,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            days.sublist(0, 31).reversed.toList(),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          key: focusKey,
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            days.sublist(31, 32),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            days.sublist(32),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ScrollController to your CustomListView. And when you set your state use the controller to animate to the position that you just selected.

ScrollController has a method:

```
Future<Void> animateTo(
  double offset, {
  @required Duration duration,
  @required Curve curve,
})
```

Where offset is the position you want to animate to.

Comment: I saw some references to that, but I wasn't sure where that controller method should go. The setState is called from a parent class. I'm building the list, but where would I call `animateTo` between building and returning?

Comment: Also, why can't I just have a new one? Seems like it would look bad when the days change out _and_ a scroll happens. I just want this thing to re-init completely.

Comment: declare the controller as a class variable and then in the CustomScrollView pass the controller in the parameter named "controller". When you do setState in that method after updating the list use your controller object to call the animateTo method

Comment: your class DaysManager is stateless. I believe you are using it inside a StatefulWidget in which you are calling set state. When you are calling setState your DaysManager should rebuild with the new data and not with the old data. Can you please show some screenshots of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That’s exactly right and it _does_ rebuild with the new data. But it keeps its scroll position. As in, it’s replacing the data, but not resetting the scroll.

Comment: I think when you are passing the focusDate in the constructor you are setting the index of the selected date.

Comment: I am and that would be in the middle of the list. But that’s not being respected when the list is rebuilt because the list is keeping its scroll position. That’s useful when building infinite lists, but I want it to reset when it’s rebuilt. That’s why I’m asking why I can’t just get a brand new CustomScrollView.

Comment: can you please remove the focus key and then try?

Comment: The focus key is what is forcing the list to be at the correct position when it’s loaded. Without it, the list will be rendered with the top most index at the top of the viewport.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the code so that I can run the code on my local machine?

Comment: Yep. No problem. I’ll throw it up on GitHub and let you know. Probably an hour or so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194062/discussion-between-nick-tdr-and-will-luce).

Comment: not sure if you get notifications for chats...Please respond if you see it. Thanks

Comment: I posted another question with some modifications to your code. I hope that is okay. Here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364950/listview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-correct-offset-position-after-its-built-again#56365266

Answer (score 0):

```
        ScrollController _scrollController;
        @override
        void initState() {
          super.initState();
          _scrollController = new ScrollController();
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              _scrollController.animateTo(index*(YOUR_VIEW_HEIGHT), duration: new Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.ease);
            }, child: Text("Item   $index"));
          }, controller: _scrollController,);
        }
```

Comment: @WillLuce Button is just for reference your view will be at the place of button.