# ListVIew doesn't scroll to the correct offset position after its built again

Tags: flutter

I want the listview to start with an offset. Which I am trying to achieve by using below code in the ListView.

> controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 30 * ITEM_HEIGHT),

Initially on the first load the list is loaded with the correct offset.

When the list is built again by calling set state from the parent widget, the list gets updated but the scroll offset behaves weird.

There are two scenarios:

1. I don't scroll the list: After this if the set state is called everything works fine. List gets updated and is always at the correct offset.
2. I scroll the list: if I scroll the list and then the list is rebuilt, 
   the scroll offset is off by a few items. The list gets updated which is fine.

Is it because when I scroll it keeps the last scroll position and that offsets my calculation? Which I think should not happen as it is a state less widget.

```
class DaysManager extends StatelessWidget {
  final int daysBeforeFocusDate = 30;
  final int totalDaysToInit = 61;
  static final double ITEM_HEIGHT = 108.00;

  ScrollController scrollController;

  List<Day> days;

  DaysManager({DateTime focusDate}) {
      final DateTime startDate =
      focusDate.subtract(Duration(days: daysBeforeFocusDate));
      days = List.generate(totalDaysToInit, (int index) {
      return Day(
       date: startDate.add(
        Duration(days: index),
    ),
  );
});

scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 30 *ITEM_HEIGHT);
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return _buildScrollView();
  }

  ListView _buildScrollView() {
    ListView listView = ListView.builder(
    cacheExtent: 0,
    controller: scrollController,
    itemCount: days.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return days[index];
     });

    return listView;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Where do you have this `scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 30 *ITEM_HEIGHT);
}`? Directly inside a class or method?

Comment: I have added the code. Please see there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reached out the the Flutter Slack community and got an answer that works. All credit to Loushou over there. Here's a copy of that conversation.

`ScrollController` saves it’s scroll position inside the `PageStorage` record of the *list it is attached to*… not of it’s own PageStorage. because of this, when the widget is recreated, since you do not specify a new `key` for the listview widget, it reuses the same key (one of the many optimizations internal to flutter for performance). you can solve this by adding two lines:

```
import 'dart:math';
...
ListView listView = ListView.builder(
  key: ValueKey<int>(Random(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch).nextInt(4294967296)),
...
```

You need to give the listview a new, random `key` every time you recreate it, so that it does not load up it’s `PageStorage` values.

here is the full, updated code for `DaysManager` from your example code:

```
class DaysManager extends StatelessWidget {
  final int daysBeforeFocusDate = 30;
  final int totalDaysToInit = 61;
  static final double ITEM_HEIGHT = 108.00;

  ScrollController scrollController;

  List<Day> days;

  DaysManager({
    DateTime focusDate,
  }) {
    final DateTime startDate = focusDate.subtract(Duration(days: daysBeforeFocusDate));
    days = List.generate(totalDaysToInit, (int index) {
      return Day(
        date: startDate.add(
          Duration(days: index),
        ),
      );
    });

    scrollController = ScrollController(
      initialScrollOffset: 30 *ITEM_HEIGHT,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildScrollView();
  }

  ListView _buildScrollView() {
    ListView listView = ListView.builder(
      key: ValueKey<int>(Random(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch).nextInt(4294967296)),
      cacheExtent: 0,
      controller: scrollController,
      itemCount: days.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return days[index];
      });

    return listView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Once I realized that we _did not_ want to maintain the scroll position between draws, and instead wanted to reset it to the top of the new selected item (exactly 30 down the list), i understood the problem and created the solution. then i explained why this is the solution. thanks @will-luce for the shout out

Comment: wow this is great. Finally we got a solution to this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Although I need to understand what PageStorage is and how it works, what kind of information it stores. If you know more about please do explain.

Comment: PageStorage holds key value pairs for all sorts of data on many Flutter core widgets. You can even leverage it for your own widgets. It is all based on the Key of the widget though. Think of it as global storage space for data specific to every Stateful widget. It allows you to persist data for widgets, even through complete widget destruction, as long as you use the same Key. In many ways, it is like Flutter's internal state-management. Here is a good video about Keys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: ...and an article about PageStorage https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@tensor/persisting-user-interface-state-and-building-bottom-navigation-bars-in-dart-s-flutter-framework

Comment: Did you figure out how you'd go about getting/setting this position from PageStorage? It's weird to me... sounds like a statelesswidget that is somewhat stateful...

Comment: I think using UniqeKey() is preferred over such a randomized approach
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UniqueKey-class.html