# How to build a Twitter like feed in Flutter with support for Animations

Tags: flutter, flutter-animatedlist

I want to build a feed similar to `Twitter` in Flutter

[image: Add newer tweets above the fold on pull to refresh]

Looking at [Will Luce's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385637/3667647), I understood that we are expected to change the `Key` of the `ListView`, for the `ScrollController` to *not* retain the original list's offset, and the `ListView` to retain the screen position of the focused items (I guess using the items' `Key`s).

But I want to implement this with `AnimatedList` since I need support for animations as well. But I can't animate items if the list view's `Key` - `GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>` changes. Is there any other way?